# How to add ".2" in my bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, math, printf

My bash script is

```
read -p "num 1: " num1
read -p "num 2: " num2
tmbk=$(echo $num1 + $num2 | bc | sed '
    s/^\./0./     # .2 -> 0.2
    s/^-\./-0./   # -.2 -> -0.2
    s/\.0*$//     # 2.000 -> 2
');
printf "result : %'d\n" $tmbk
```

I use `printf "%'d\n"` to separate 3 zero with point. If I use `printf "%s\n"` to string, this command does not separate 3 zero with point.

My question: 
if I input 0.1 in `num1` and 0.1 in `num2`, why does the result look like this?

```
printf : 0.2: invalid number
result : 0
```

I want my bash script to print `result: 0.2` and not `invalid number`

Answer (score 4):

`%d` is for integers. Try `%f` instead.

Comment: thank you for your help. but I want my bash script result is for integers with separated point ( 1.000.000 ) and float ( 0.2 ). can I use regex for the result ?

Comment: must be a strange locale where 1.000 is an integer but 0.1 is a float.

Answer (score 1):

how about in this way?

```
echo "num 1 :"
read num1
echo "num 2 :"
read num2
awk -v a="$num1" -v b="$num2" 'BEGIN{print "result:" a+b}';
```

if you need certain format for output, you could use `printf` in awk

Comment: @user2433277 then use print "result: %'f... (you'll have trouble with the ' inside '' but that's another problem)

Answer (score 0):

so you want to see '.' as a thousand separator but also as a decimal point?
Bad idea because then you can't determine whether 1.234 is a float or an integer.

locales are there for handling such things (requires these locales to be installed):

```
for loc in C en_US de_DE de_CH; do 
    LC_NUMERIC=$loc
    printf "%'d\t%'f\t%s\n" 1234 1234 $loc
done
```

Result:

```
1234    1234.000000     C
1,234   1,234.000000    en_US
1.234   1.234,000000    de_DE
1'234   1'234.000000    de_CH
```

As you see none of these locales uses the same character for thousand separator and as decimal point and that's good.

once you've chosen a proper locale you can only agree with Kent. awk is better than bc if you don't like bc's formatting.

Answer (score 0):

your requirement is a bit strange " integers with separated point ( 1.000.000 )", what have you been working on ??

Also i would make a small addition in the line ..... echo "scale=4; $num1 + $num2" | bc

for the "invalid number output" :: the printf for bash uses the same formating that's available in the printf() function of C , as part of libc library.... hence

```
%d , %i : stands for integers 
%g , %f : stands for floating point ... likewise ,
```

this uses the same validations that the printf() would use in a c - program , hence puts the comment "invalid number" on encountring a float where it expects a integer , as in the following :

```
 Kaizen ~
  $ printf "result : %'d\n" 2.3
   -bash: printf: 2.3: invalid number
  result : 2

Kaizen ~
 $ printf "result : %'li\n" 2.3
  -bash: printf: 2.3: invalid number
 result : 2
```

I do agree with what @ignacio has suggested , so if you are going to use floating point values to print then you should put a %g or better a %f in your code. The following should work fine for all scenario's  in your code :

```
Kaizen ~
 $ printf "result : %'f\n" 2.3
result : 2.300000

Kaizen ~
 $ printf "result : %'g\n" 2.3
result : 2.3
```